# how to run sql including comments?

Tags: sql, comments, pgadmin

How I can execute sql statements including comments in pgadmin sql editor?

Neither `--` nor `/*` syntax is working, that is gives me this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "﻿"
LINE 1: ﻿/*
```

Comment: Do you have closing tags as well? /*.... */

Comment: That is weird, I checked syntax for pgadmin (http://dave.webdev.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pg/sql-syntax.html#sql-syntax-comments) and c style comments are supported...

Comment: ... just there isn't a nested comment. Is there? Anyway test with trivial comments, just to check if in your particular case comments are not supported.

Comment: Check what the compiler you're using says about 'escape' characters in strings.  Can you also post an example.

Answer (score 0):

For comments in PGAdmin SQL editor use -- or /*.... */ notation.

If you use something like

```
""" comment """
select * from database
```

you get following syntax error

```
 ERROR:  syntax error at or near """" comment """".
```